# Laravel 5.3 - How to keep the session message until the users logs out

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.3

I am sending a welcome message to user after registration. I have modified the trait method in my controller like so:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        Session::set('message','messages.welcome');

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('message', 'messages.welcome');
    }
```

I have also tried `$request->session()->put('message','messages.welcome');` instead of `Session::set('message','messages.welcome');` but it gave me the same result.

And then I am showing the message in the view like this:

```
@if (session('message'))
   @include(session('message'))
@endif
```

But when I refresh the view the messages disappears, how can I keep the messages until the user logs out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$request->session()->put('message','messages.welcome');
```

The docs only recommend using the helper function or `$request` for dealing with sessions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data

Comment: I have tried that one already and it doesn't work, the message still disappears if I refresh the page.

Comment: Laravel keeps messing with the `sessions` which seems to be causing issues for a lot of people,this link may be helpful: http://laravel.io/forum/09-07-2016-session-not-saving-laravel-53

Answer (score 0):

First write use statement

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

then modify your method like :

```
public function register(Request $request)
   {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        #$request->session()->put('message', 'messages.welcome'); #this will also work

        Session::put('message', 'messages.welcome');

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

then when you need it just call `Session::get('message');`