# Laravel 5.3 - return redirect with a variable

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to send a variable in a redirect, but it doesn't work, how can I send a variable with when returning back to the same page?

This is was my attempt:

```
       $player = Player::updateOrCreate(
          [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
          ],
          [
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'nationality' => $request->nationality,
            'birthday' => $request->birthday,
            'club' => $request->club,
          ]
        );

        return Redirect::route('admin.articles.index', compact('player'));
        //return redirect()->back()->with(['player' => $player]);
```

Comment: Can we see the routes.php file

Comment: it is redirecting but variable is not being sent, so it has nothing to do with the routes

Comment: you are aware, that you have to fetch the variables from session then ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like:

```
    $player = 'player_namne';
    return back()->with(compact('player'));
```

in you function, you have to access it in your view ( or controller ) like that:

```
@if(session('player'))
    {{ session('player') }}
@endif
```

Comment: yes, I was trying to avoid using session, since session variables seem to go away on refreshing the page

Comment: yeah flashed session variables like the ones included in a redirect do. If you want to keep variables even after refreshing the page. You have to store them in a session ( not as flash variable ) or you include it in a GET - Variable

Comment: I have tried saving the variable in session, I even posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761213/laravel-5-3-how-to-keep-the-session-message-until-the-users-logs-out). I am not sure what do you mean by included in the GET -Variable?

Comment: get variables are the things behind the ? in   urls like index.php?name=test&last_name=another

Answer (score 0):

if you need the value even after refreshing the page then modify like below

```
$player = 'player_name';
Session::put('plName', $player);
```

Then when you need it again just call it `Session::get('plName');`

if you need it temporarily `Session::flash('plName', $player);`

You also need the use statement `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;`